# Изменить содержание файла

Tags: php, php7

Есть файл в котором хранится текст, нужно вместо каждого символа подставить 0 или 1 рандомным образом.
Я сделал функцию, но почему-то вместо всего текста записывается только один символ.

```html
$strSource = implode(file('file/change value.txt')); // исходная строка
            // 0
            $arraySource0 = str_split($strSource);
            $arrayBinary0 = array_map(function() {
                return 0;
            }, $arraySource0);
            // 1
            $arraySource1 = str_split($strSource);
            $arrayBinary1 = array_map(function() {
                return 1;
            }, $arraySource1);
            // random
            $arraySourceRand = str_split($strSource);
            $arrayBinaryRand = array_map(function() {
                return rand(0, 1);
            }, $arraySourceRand);

            $strBinary = implode($arrayBinary0); // закодированная строка
            $strBinary = implode($arrayBinary1); // закодированная строка
            $strBinary = implode($arrayBinaryRand); // закодированная строка

            file_put_contents("file/change value.txt", $strBinary0); // поместить новое значение в файл
            file_put_contents("file/change value.txt", $strBinary1); // поместить новое значение в файл
            file_put_contents("file/change value.txt", $strBinaryRand); // поместить новое значение в файл

            echo "Содержание файла:"."</br>".$strBinary."</br>";
            echo "Значение файла изменено!"."</br>"."Метод: VISR (Германия)";
```

Кто знает в чем проблема?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для записи в файл строки используйте такую команду:

```
file_put_contents("file.txt", $strBinary);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Я в двух темах поставлю ваш ответ как правельный

Comment: а если нужно сначала записать одни единицы, потом все нули, а потом рандомно. А то у меня после моей проверки полностью все стирается из файла